Equivalent 'svDialogs' for r4.4.1 version?
Is there an equivalent of 'svDialogs' package for R4.4.1 version ? My objective is to generate a pop-up using R. This pop up will then contains a barecode obtain with a barecode scanner.
I've tried to find some equivalent packages but nothing
